# Error compiling AODV-UU (modversions.h: No such file)

Tags: kernel, vmware, gcc

i have to compile aodv routing protokol, but i get error like this

```
make -C /home/andri/Downloads/aodv-uu-0.9.6/lnx KERNEL_DIR=/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/build KCC=gcc XDEFS=-DDEBUG
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/andri/Downloads/aodv-uu-0.9.6/lnx'
gcc -Wall -Wno-strict-aliasing -O2 -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -nostdinc -DMODVERSIONS -include /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/build/include/linux/modversions.h -I /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include -I/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/build/include -DDEBUG -c -o kaodv-mod.o kaodv-mod.c
cc1: fatal error: /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/build/include/linux/modversions.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [kaodv-mod.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/andri/Downloads/aodv-uu-0.9.6/lnx'
make: *** [kaodv] Error 2
```

please help me.

Comment: What's the output of `uname -a`? Is `linux-headers-generic` installed?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install linux-headers

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.13.0-24
```

I am not sure this will be enough, because I don't know which other packages you do not have installed.

Comment: If you install the package `linux-headers-generic` it will ensure that you'll get the new headers each time there's a new kernel and have to recompile.

Comment: Up to the previous mentiones the moduleversions.h is to be found in `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic/include/config/modversions.h`. Simply run `find / -name "modversions.h"` and either rewrite the makefile or add that path to the includes.

Comment: Now i have another problem, like this /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/build/include/uapi/asm-generic/int-ll64.h:11:29: fatal error: asm/bitsperlong.h: No such file or directory
 #include <asm/bitsperlong.h>
please help me

Comment: Type `sudo apt-get install linux-libc-dev`.

Comment: it's not work for my problem, please help me